# WordPress Query by custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to perform a custom query based upon a search result and the results are not coming through. I've looked at my code and it appears to be right:

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'images',
            'post_status'   =>  'publish',
            'posts_per_page'    =>  10,
            'paged'         =>  $paged,
            's'             =>  $state,
            'tax_query' => array(                     //(array) - use taxonomy parameters (available with Version 3.1).
              array(
                'taxonomy' => 'type',                //(string) - Taxonomy.
                'field' => 'slug',                    //(string) - Select taxonomy term by ('id' or 'slug')
                'terms' => array( 'first-images', 'second-images' ),    //(int/string/array) - Taxonomy term(s).
                'include_children' => true,           //(bool) - Whether or not to include children for hierarchical taxonomies. Defaults to true.
                'operator' => 'IN' 
                )                   //(string) - Operator to test. Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
              ),
            ); 

            $search = new wp_query( $args ); ?>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you provide more debug details? Are $state and $paged available and do they have a valid result? Whats the var_dump of $search?

Comment: Are the terms really plural, e.g. is the term 'first-images' or 'first-image'?

Comment: $state is just a plain $_GET['state'], and $paged is taken from the codex and I've used it countless times on the same site. That won't be the issue affecting the above.